# The use of "in" keyword in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes with one common column "user_id".
Let's call the larger one 'total_users' and smaller one called 'converted_users' ('converted_users' is a subset of 'total_users').

I want to add a column to 'total_users' that flags whether each user_id occurs in converted_users['user_id'] as True or False.

I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

total_users = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,888888,999999]})
converted_users = pd.DataFrame({"user_id":[33333,44444,77777,888888]})

for i in range(len(total_users['user_id'])):
    if total_users['user_id'][i] in list(converted_users['user_id']):
        total_users['converted'] = True
    else:
        pass
```

it works fine. However, when I removed list() function, and it gives me a wrong number. Can anyone give me any insights on this issue?